# Menu not showing correctly in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

A site I'm creating is showing the front page exactly as its supposed to do in both Chrome and Safari, but when I test in Firefox the menu isn't showed correctly.
- All browsers are the latest versions and on a mac.

[Here's a screenshot comparing Firefox and Safari, respectively!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlECQ.png)

And here's the css-code I use for the menu, pardon the mess.

```
nav {
width: 650px;
height: 220px;
margin: 10px auto;
}

nav ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
}

nav ul li {
margin: 10px;
display: inline-block;
height: 100px;
line-height: 200px;
}
```

I've tried with different methods, but this messes up the menu in the working browsers.

Here's the HTML code for the nav-bar, as per request:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><h2><a href="#cykler.html">Cykler</a></h2></li>
    <li><h2><a href="#service.html">Service</a></h2></li>
    <li><a href="#index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" name="logo" alt="Søgaard Cykler" width="220" height="200"></a></li>
    <li><h2><a href="#info.html">Info</a></h2></li>
    <li><h2><a href="#kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></h2></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

And here is a link to the functioning code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DaCqS/

Comment: is it possible to see your HTML or even better do you have a viewable URL?

Comment: Added the html code to the question

Comment: Have you tried using floats for the <li>, not sure you need display:inline-block... just taking a guess here without being able to play with the physical code.

Comment: You can play with the code now, I've added a jsfiddle-link

Comment: I've rolled back the question to the version including the HTML and CSS (this is to ensure the question is self-contained, and not dependent on an external site for hosting the relevant code). I've also re-added the [tag:html] tag.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to avoid line-height for positioning elements. Margins are much more effective. Get rid of the line-height and try using a

```
margin-top:100px;
```

on either the nav or the ul.

**EDIT**: Now that I see your HTML... Since the big center logo is stylistically different from the four buttons, you should keep their CSS selectors separate. None of your current CSS is able to differentiate between these four buttons and the big center logo. A quick and easy way to fix this is to add this style:

```
nav ui li h2 {margin-top:100px;}
```

Comment: A margin specification won't help as it will move the WHOLE nav down. I've already specified the position of the nav-bar from the top in nav {}, but I found out removing the line-height from nav ul li {} didn't change anything in any browsers, so no need for that bit of code. - Now I am not using line-height to position my elements, but the issue persists. I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: You just need a way to target ONLY those four buttons and not the whole nav. Make use of those h2's you already have!

Comment: That code doesn't change anything.. I've updated the question with a jsfiddle (from the original code)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I've floated the the `<li>` and used the margin-top:100px for the h2.

try this and let me know if that fixes it http://jsfiddle.net/hfxKW/

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/WWkWw/

```
.top-menu{
    background-image:url('foo/logo.png');
    height:22px;
}
.left{
    float:left;
}
.right{
    float:right;
}
.top-menu li{
    margin:60px 10px 10px 10px;
    height:100px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
<ul class="top-menu">
<li class="left"><h2><a href="#cykler.html">Cykler</a></h2></li>
<li class="left"><h2><a href="#service.html">Service</a></h2></li>
<li class="right"><h2><a href="#info.html">Info</a></h2></li>
<li class="left"><h2><a href="#kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></h2></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```